# Copying a long command from history in terminal

Tags: shortcuts, copy

Having found an old (long) command from history I want to copy, modify and execute it. Is there a shortcut key to copy that long string? I do not use mouse.

Comment: Are you in a TTY or a GUI terminal emulator. And how exactly did you find that command in your history?

Comment: in terminal I simply keep pressing up arrow to find the old command

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/302263/selecting-text-in-the-terminal-without-using-the-mouse

Comment: that solution assumes I have xsel -- I have xclip; It assumes I have used Ctrl+P to look for older command -- I simply use up-arrow; and it requires the command xsel to paste -- I prefer to use the normal Shift+Ctrl+V in terminal and Ctrl+V outside it. In fact sometimes I want to paste that text outside the terminal

Comment: I typically save history periodically, so I have very old commands once history gets full and lost. `history > hist_Aug2016` That is just a text file which I can copy from, search or use anyway I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and start typing a text from a command that you want to get from the history. The latest command with the text that you typed in will appear. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> again to move to the next command, which contains entered text, until you get the command you are searching for. Then you can move within command with <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> keys and change it as you like. When you are done, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You don't need to copy the command as you can recall it anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes there is. Just enter an **exclamation mark (!)** followed by the command serial number which you can get it from history. For detailed example Open up a terminal and type  command

```
history
```

You will definitely see a list of commands you entered with serial number in the left side against each command say as follows.
[image: history example] 
well if you want to execute    **sudo apt-cache search Inkscape** the slno concerned with that command in the above pic is 311 so in the terminal just enter

```
!311
```

Well if you want to edit the before executing the command while using above method , you need to set *histverify ON* so that it will alsways ask for verification before executing. So for that just execute the command once for hassle free use of above method as follows :

```
shopt -s histverify
```

Thats it ,

Comment: That is certainly a very quick way to execute commands from history, but elmclose wants to edit it before executing.

Comment: Ok . For that set histverify to ON , this will ask for it. I wll update my answer. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: These are all excellent tips that I didn't know about. However I sometimes need to paste the string outside the terminal such as gedit.