# Can two PCs with Ubuntu share the clipboard buffer?

Tags: networking, clipboard

I need to copy text on the first PC and paste on the second. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the PCs are on the same network, it is possible.
Software like [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) can do it.

> Synergy brings your devices together in one cohesive experience.
>
> - Seamlessly move your mouse to any computer and start typing.
> - Works on all major operating systems (Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux).
> - Share your clipboard (copy and paste) between your computers.

Comment: I love you! This is what I need! And this is working!

Comment: I use synergy a lot, wonderful software. hope you support them

Answer (score 4):

*(For most cases, `synergy` will be more useful than this - see @jonvon's answer.)*

There is a more low-level solution similar to `synergy` - it's called **`x2x`** - like "X to X", joining two X screens together.

With two X displays, it can make the mouse switch to the other display when it touches the edge of the screen that is next to the other screen, which feels like it's just one mouse pointer on one big screen - while it actually moved to another computer, and switched over the keyboard control too.

For the task at hand, `x2x` shares the X selection between the two computers. When used with windows, it interacts with the clipboard.

It is available as the package `x2x` in Ubuntu, but there is also a Cygwin build, available from the cygwin setup. The cygwin version allows to connect to a Windows screen, without running X there.

For options, see [`man x2x`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/x2x.1.html).
(Make sure you use one of the options like `-west` - that activates the more interesting mode of operation.)

Comment: Thank you, it is interesting for testing. But already now with Synergy no one will guess that my second monitor not connected to the same PC :)

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Yeah, I know this fascination :) I remember when I first used `x2x` - I was working remote on both screens. When going to the other screen, the mouse pointer effectively went from Hongkong to Sweden. Via Germany.

Comment: This might be useful when using `x2x`: https://askubuntu.com/a/167591/75050

Answer (score 3):

You can interact with the X clipboard (and the promary selection) using `xclip`.
The specific task in your question, paste text that was copied elsewhere, requires to copy over the clipboard contents.
You can use `ssh` to pipe the text from one clipboard to the other. That works best with password-less ssh login of course:

After copying on on firstPc, you run on secondPc:

```
$ ssh firstPc 'DISPLAY=:0 xclip -o -selection clipboard' | xclip -i  -selection clipboard
```

Now, you can paste on secondPc.

Note that a clipboard can not only contain text, but also more structured data. It can even contain the same data in multiple formats.

Comment: I got much more with Synergy - my mouse in two PC! But thank you for answer.

Comment: Sure, I guessed the synergy answer is more useful for you - but there may be later reader interested in this, as it matches the question text pretty well. Said that, you reminded me that I know another solution, more similar to synergy; It's somewhat in between, you will still use synergy.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this neat little online clipboard called [IP-Share](http://www.ipshare.net/). I found it very useful when you want to copy/paste small text and/or files between computers or mobile devices within the same network!