# Paste selected content with the keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, navigation

In Ubuntu, it's possible to select content and paste it with the mouse middle-click. Is there any keyboard shortcut to paste the selected content so I don't need to use the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different kinds of copy&paste. The one using Ctrl-C / Ctrl-V is usually managed by the window manager, while the middle-click paste comes from the X window system. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/167577/907096) answer for a more complete explanation.

It sounds like you want to emulate the middle-click paste from X11 with the keyboard. This is apparently not straightforward. You could try to emulate the middle mouse button using something like `xbindkeys`. Some inspiration may be found [here](https://superuser.com/a/1604024) although it looks like it is for Macs.

See also the man page for [xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) which is a terminal program allowing to manipulate the X11 selection by terminal commands, which you may then be able bind to a key.

Answer (score 0):

Like on most other operating systems, CTRL+V is for pasting. CTRL+C is for copying selected content and CTRL+X cuts content if the source of the content is editable.

*Addition 1*: in the terminal you need to press SHIFT+CTRL+V / SHIFT+CTRL+C / SHIFT+CTRL+X

Comment: NOTE: The Terminal needs the SHIFT key to be held down while doing that.

Comment: It's possible to paste content without using Ctrl+C in Ubuntu. You can select the content and paste with mouse-middle click. My question is: how to use the keyboard to paste the content selected without using Ctrl+C, and Ctrl+V: or, can I execute the same operation that the mouse middle-click does with the keyboard?