Middle mouse click paste seems broken in 24.04
When i try to middle-mouse-click-paste something for example into gnome-terminal, sometimes it just beeps, sometimes it works once but if i do it again it just repeats the previous marked content.
This also happens kind of unpredictably in other programs like firefox, gedit and so on.
i already tried to disable and re-enable in gnome-tweaks, no effect.
having these problems on two different machines now. Had to reinstall fresh because do-release-upgrade was unbootable after. 24.04 the worst distro release in over a decade.
since googling brought nothing up i start a thread here.

Maybe a GNOME issue. Works in Linux Mint 22 based on Ubuntu 24.04

Maybe this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/167570/how-does-middle-click-paste-work

Funny thing: when i connect to a server through ssh the middle mouse click into the terminal to the remote shell always works.

I have a slightly different 'problem' - my mouse middle-click now (with 24.04) pastes at the cursor position in the text, not the mouse position.
If I highlight text, then the first mouse middle-click is a re-paste back onto the highlighted text. I need to left-click the mouse THEN middle-click to paste. Double the clicks. Shocking I know...
(I find the highlight text | move mouse | middle-click to paste text is a really handy feature of Ubuntu. Sad it's not working as before.)
Is there a menu option that controls this behaviour?

@AntC in the terminal this was always the behavior and i can confirm it still persists. However, when i middle mouse click into a text in gedit it gets inserted at the cursor position.

Good to know that I'm not the only one with this problem (ANNOYING). Why is it that every time we update Ubuntu we need to fix things?

Always works in Terminal but copy (marking) from e.g. Browser only work once (pastes into Terminal ok) but I have to copy (mark) something in Terminal again to copy from Browser again.

It looks like this issue (or at least very similar one) has been fixed in GNOME/Mutter, but I'm not sure how to check if that's made it into the version that Ubuntu is currently using. The issue was reported for mutter 46.1 and I've got 46.2 installed. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/3498
Until it's fixed, I also found middle click paste works correctly if I run on Xorg instead of Wayland, so you could try that as a workaround.

You are right, on the other computer i am in X11 and there it works as usual. this is (ANOTHER) wayland issue. The last computer i ran wayland on now gave me another reason not to. So much fun.

It looks like the fix was back-ported for 46.3, which isn't yet in 24.04.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/3850
